# Trigger observer on Magento order status change not work with sales_order_save_after

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, observer-pattern

I have module to change the status of pending orders to processing in observer when event sales_order_save_after called . i could get the order and the order id but the function of save status is not working . I am not sure if i use the correct event in the observer because it doesnt work and i also changed it to sales_order_save_commit_after but not work as well
the log file run and appear the correct order id but no action on the status of order
this is the code :

```
class ChangeOrder_Observerstatus_Model_Observer 
{

    public function autoOrderevent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)

    {

        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
        $order1 = Mage::getModel('sales/order')>loadByIncrementID($order_id);
        $order1->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true)->save();
        Mage::log($order_id, null, 'test_.log');

    }
}
```